# How shall I integrate this multivariable function when one of the variable in the function is in the form of limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

How shall I integrate this multivariable function when one of the variable in the function is in the form of limits:

$$\int \left[     f(x,y)      \right]^{y=b}_{y=0} \, dx$$

Can I proceed by ignoring the limits:

$$\int f(x,y) \, dx$$

If yes, how can it be justified?

Comment: I was confused a bit by seeing such an expression in my text. Anyway now I understand what it means.

Comment: Yes. Double integration with limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it simply means:
$$
\int f(x,b)-f(x,0) dx=\int f(x,b)dx - \int f(x,0)dx
$$

Comment: Thanks. I get it.